# Stack Exchange seems to be down

Tags: discussion, downtime

Meta Stack Exchange and many other sites in the network seem to be down, what's happening?

[image]

(In case you were wondering: this question was posted via the officially deprecated Stack Exchange iOS app.)

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with Fastly, half the internet is down

Comment: related: https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-57399628

Comment: They're working on a fix: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1402213937983205376?s=20 - I'll leave it to staff to provide an answer (if they want).

Comment: This was indeed a problem with Fastly, seems to be fixed now (although a bit sluggish).

Comment: It works from here in Europe. Is there still a problem network-wide for users in other areas?

Comment: There should really be a backup in place. Let's be honest, how on earth are the staff at Fastly meant to fix anything if Stackoverflow is down?! :-D

Comment: It's just not S.E. Google forms was experiencing the same https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBNn4.png

Comment: Fixed: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver ⁉️

Comment: cf. https://techcrunch.com/2021/06/08/numerous-popular-websites-are-facing-an-outage/

Comment: Remind us: What is the *official* Twitter account for these situations?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q one that is not used (Stackstatus)

Comment: Do we have any info on this that's more detailed than "Fastly did something that messed up their CDN"?

Comment: [Fastly Incident Report](https://status.fastly.com/incidents/vpk0ssybt3bj), [DownDetector Report](https://downdetector.com/status/fastly/news/392592-problems-at-fastly/), [Kentik Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6E5E.png). - It was a configuration error at Fastly.